# Determining if a particular query produces any results or has any results using Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a particular function which checks if a particular row matches the query condition.If it does then I retrieve the value and store it in my variable , if it doesnot have a value I insert it.However I have a try{} catch{} block which determines if it exists or not.If it goes inside a catch block , I call a function which will insert a record in that table , I would like to know is this approach good ,Calling a function inside a catch block , is it ok, what are the alternatives to find out if my query returns a result or not.Here is my code

```
public void CheckApplicationNo(string TableName,string BranchNo)
    {
        try
        {
            var appno = (from app in dt.sys_Keys
                         where app.TableName == TableName && app.BranchNo.ToString() == BranchNo
                         select app.NewValue).Single();

                Global.ApplicationNo = appno.ToString();
                UpdateApplicationNo("Data_Customer_Log", Global.BranchNo);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            InsertApplicationNo(); 
        }


    }
```

Any suggestons are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use .SingleOrDefault()

```
select app.NewValue).SingleOrDefault(); 

    if (appno == null)
    {
      InsertApplicationNo();  
    }
    else
    {
     ..
    }
```

It returns null if there are no results.

Comment: wont it give error if there are no results , can you explain SingleorDefault() a bit.Thanks

Comment: SingleOrDefault is the same as Single except that it does not throw an exception when there are no results, instead it returns the default value (most of the times null)

Comment: great , that means if no rsults are found , I will be returned  a null , right , got it thanks

Comment: I also update using Single , so do you recommend I should use SingleOrDefault there as well , thanks

Comment: That i cannot answer without the code. In general use Single if you really always expect a result. If due to some strange situation you do not get a result, the exception will help you realize that you have a bug or data corruption or sthing like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.Any()` extension method instead:

```
dt.sys_Keys.Any(app.TableName == TableName && app.BranchNo.ToString() == BranchNo)
```

this will return a boolean value, so you can easily build an if/else block with it.

Comment: this will work, but it requires an extra query whereas SingleOrDefault will do all in one.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek , do you agree with what Pleun has to say , what approach is better , thanks

Comment: If you need that `appno.ToString()` to perform the update `SingleOrDefault` whould be a better choice. From the further code this ApplicationNo is never used, so I'm not sure it is necessary for you.

Comment: I believe SingleOrDefault should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a good way to handle this in catch section. What if you get any other type of exception?

Try to check whether appno exists in an if else statement instead of employing exceptions.

```
public void CheckApplicationNo(string TableName,string BranchNo)
    {
        try
        {
            var appno = (from app in dt.sys_Keys
                         where app.TableName == TableName && app.BranchNo.ToString() == BranchNo
                         select app.NewValue).SingleOrDefault();
            if(appno == null)
                InsertApplicationNo();
            else
            {
                Global.ApplicationNo = appno.ToString();
                UpdateApplicationNo("Data_Customer_Log", Global.BranchNo);
            }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }


}
```

Comment: thanks , dont you think if there are no results it will go inside catch block and then I wont be able to insert record.

Comment: Since I have added a SingleOrDefault to the query; it will just return null if no results and there will be no exception, thus catch block can be used on it's purpose, just handling exceptions.